# How to calculate expected value from the distribution?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am investigation the following task
Could you please elaborate why Expected value of Z equals `2/3` ? (the last line on the photo `'From this we obtain EZ = 2/3'`)

I thought it should be `z * z` where `z = 1` (the answer is 1 instead of 2/3)

[image]

Comment: by definition, the expected value is $\int_{0}^{1} z \times 2z~dz$.

Comment: Please rephrase the question yourself instead of embedding it as a picture.